# Custom Listview + Xmlparser + Actionbar 4.2 Sherlock Searchview

Tags: android, search, xml-parsing, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

I have a custom ListView that Get baseadapter by passing xml data ArrayList.

I want to perform a search using ActionbarSherlock 4.2 Searchview, so after user puts an text and press the button it will inflate a new layout with the results.

**What is the best guideline?**

- Should I implement Filterable on BaseAdapter? And if yes, how I handle to get tostring() from Sherlock Searchview instead of filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);?
- Should I create a new BaseAdapter to download only the listview hint by the search? And If yes, Do you have any sample or tutorial to link?
- Or anyother way?

**Custom Listview:**

```
public class CustomizedListView extends ListFragment {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }



        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);        
        setListAdapter(adapter);



    }   
}
```

**BaseAdapter:**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private FragmentActivity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


    public LazyAdapter(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = fragmentActivity;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**Sherlock ActionBar SearchView:**

```
public abstract class BaseSampleActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    PageIndicator mIndicator;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        searchView.setQueryHint("Procure pelo nome");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent search = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchableActivity.class);
            search.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            search.putExtra(query, query);
            startActivityForResult(search, 0);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });

        menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search_inverse)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        return true;
    }
```

The NewActivity:

```
public class SearchableActivity extends SherlockListActivity{

    // All static variables
        static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
        static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
        static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
        static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    private String message;
    private ListView list;
    private LazyAdapterS adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        message = getIntent().getExtras().getString(query);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_list_row);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter = new LazyAdapterS(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        ((Filterable) list.getAdapter()).Filter(message);// Error The method Filter(String) is undefined for the type Filterable
    }

}
```

UPDATE: I put the setOnQueryTextListener as Suggested by @Luksprog.
UPDATE: I´ve created a new Activity to show the results from the search, but still got a error on filter, I dont know how to handle this.

Thank you,

Comment: That is not how you call the filter method, Instead of `((Filterable) list.getAdapter()).Filter(message);` it should be : `((Filterable) list.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(message);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I implement Filterable on BaseAdapter?

If you want to use the standard filtering mechanism for an adapter(which any Android SDK adapter does), yes, you need to implement the `Filterable` interface and provide a proper implementation for it's two methods.

> And if yes, how I handle to get tostring() from Sherlock Searchview
>   instead of filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);?

Have a look at [`OnQueryTextListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html):

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      ((Filterable) listview.getAdapter()).filter(query);
      return true;
}
```

> Should I create a new BaseAdapter to download only the listview hint
>   by the search? And If yes, Do you have any sample or tutorial to link?

If you mean, parsing again the xml(using only what matches the query string) and create a new adapter to show the results, no because you'll be doing a lot of unnecessary work(especially all the network calls which you should really try move on a background thread).

If you want to show the results in a new activity then put the query `String` in the `Intent` that starts the results activity and do/redo the filtering there.

> Or anyother way?

See point one.

Comment: Ok, I´ve implemented Filterable on BaseAdapter, but the sugestion of code above doesnt work because I'm working with FragmentActivity, so How I handle this, I need to get the query, start a new activity and perform the filter?

Comment: @Marckaraujo *but the sugestion of code above doesnt work because I'm working with FragmentActivity* - I don't see the connection with the `FragmentActivity` as the `SearchView` is present in the Sherlock library. Did you actually set a `OnQueryTextListener` instance to your `SearchView`(with `setOnQueryTextListener()`)? Also try to provide more details than *doesn't work* as this is not helpful. Starting a new activity is not necessary.

Comment: I set OnQueryTextListener properly, but it shows Filterable cannot be resolved to a type, I think its because the ListView and adapter is instanced on the "CustomizedListView extends ListFragment", also I want to show the filter results in a new Activity, looks play store app, its exactly what I want, thanks Luksprog

Comment: @Marckaraujo *but it shows Filterable cannot be resolved to a type*. I don't see how that would happen if you imported the proper class: `import android.widget.Filterable;`. If you want to show the results in a new activity then pass the query string to the new activity and do the query there.

Comment: Please look at my update, I´ve created the new activity to show the results, but still get an error Filter(String) is undefined for the type Filterable

Comment: Ok, thanks mate, now its working! Just update your answer to the correct one, I´ve also implemented Asynctask in the custom listview, the only problem that its showing all the list and after one second it filters correctly, Im putting ((Filterable) list.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(message); inside onPostExecute, is it correct?

Comment: @Marckaraujo That is normal because you probably set the adapter with the whole data in the `onPostExecute` method and then filter it(which will not happen instantaneous). If you want to show the filtered items from the start then don't use the `getFilter().filter(s)` method and simply do yourself the filtering in the `doInBackground` method. To do this simply test the desired key from each `Map` against the query string and put the results in a temporary list of maps from which you'll build the adapter in the `onPostExecute`.